# What`s wrong -> cannot be instantiated

Tags: android, android-studio

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.estimote.coresdk.observation.region.Region;
import com.estimote.coresdk.service.BeaconManager;


import java.util.UUID;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

private BeaconManager beaconManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    beaconManager = new BeaconManager(getApplicationContext());

    beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        // 비콘 uuid,major minor
        public void onServiceReady() {
            beaconManager.startMonitoring(new Region());
        }
    });
}
}
```

this is my code
when I use this code
-beaconManager.startMonitoring(new Region());-
get error named cannot be instanted
how can I fixed??

http://loveiskey.tistory.com/207

this is the site where I referd

Comment: paste your log here

Answer (score 0):

Estimote [`Region`](https://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/com/estimote/coresdk/observation/region/Region.html) is an interface. You cannot instantiate interfaces. You need to instantiate some class that implements that interface instead.